# How to put figure labels above rather than below each image in a multiplot layout?

Tags: captions, positioning, subfloats

For example in the following code, each image has its label (a) (b) (c) (d) below the image. I would like to place it above the image.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{.329\textwidth}
              \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{file.pdf}
              \caption{}
          \end{subfigure}
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{.329\textwidth}
              \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{file.pdf}
              \caption{}
          \end{subfigure}
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{.329\textwidth}
              \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{file.pdf}
              \caption{}
          \end{subfigure}
      \caption{Blah.} \label{unknownFig}
\end{figure}
```

I surprisingly didn't see this information in the latex wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place the `\caption` *above* the `\includegraphics`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.329\textwidth}
      \caption{}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.329\textwidth}
      \caption{}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.329\textwidth}
      \caption{}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Blah.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```